# Choose a BidiFlow based on the first input element

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a protocol which has type `protocol: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed]`. Elements coming into the stream are messages sent by the user and elements exiting the stream are responses from the server. Encryption layers have type `encryption: BidiFlow[ByteString, ByteString, ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed]` (Akka streams provides, for instance [`TLS`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/TLS$.html) in this format). With this architecture, piping the protocol through an encryption layer boils down to:

```
protocol.join(tlsEncryptionLayer): Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed]
protocol.join(noEncryptionLayer): Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed]
```

The problem is that **I want to be able to pick the encryption layer (aka. the `BidiFlow` being `join`-ed) based on the first `ByteString`** received from the client.

#### My thoughts so far

This problem looks quite similar to [`def lazyInit[I, O, M](flowFactory: (I) ⇒ Future[Flow[I, O, M]], fallback: () ⇒ M): Flow[I, O, M]`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow$.html) for `Flow`. For instance, a `lazyInit` on `BidiFlow` would unstick me:

```
object BidiFlow {

  // This method doesn't exist, but if it did, my problem would be solved
  def lazyInit[I1, O1, I2, O2](
    bidiFactory: (I1) ⇒ BidiFlow[I1, O1, I2, O2, NotUsed]
  ): BidiFlow[I1, O1, I2, O2, NotUsed] = ???
}
```

Considering such a hypothetical function, I'd be able to write code that uses TLS when the first byte is `0x16` and fall back to no encryption otherwise. The following code typechecks, assuming the function above:

```
val encryptionLayer = BidiFlow.lazyInit[ByteString, ByteString, ByteString, ByteString](
  bidiFactory = {
    // If the very first byte is `0x16`, we are dealing with TLS
    case bstr if bstr.head == 0x16 =>
      TLS(createSSLEngine = ???, closing = ???)
        .reversed
        .atop(BidiFlow.fromFunctions(
          (inbound: TLSProtocol.SslTlsInbound) => inbound match {
            case TLSProtocol.SessionBytes(_, bytes) => bytes
            case _ => ??? // TODO: good error handling
          },
          (byteString: ByteString) => TLSProtocol.SendBytes(byteString)
        ))

    // If the first byte is anything else, assume no-encryption
    case _ => BidiFlow.identity[ByteString, ByteString]
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

After posting and looking more at the docs, I've figured out a semi-solution: since the `BidiFlow` is anyways ultimately going to be `join`-ed to a `Flow`, we can just think of the problem in terms of `Flow`'s.

```
// The protocol that may need to be encrypted
val protocol: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = ???

// A bidi that encrypts bytestrings coming through
val tlsBidi = TLS(createSSLEngine = ???, closing = ???)
  .reversed
  .atop(BidiFlow.fromFunctions(
    (inbound: TLSProtocol.SslTlsInbound) => inbound match {
      case TLSProtocol.SessionBytes(_, bytes) => bytes
      case _ => ??? // TODO: good error handling
    },
    (byteString: ByteString) => TLSProtocol.SendBytes(byteString)
  ))


// The encrypted protocol
val encryptedProtocol = Flow[ByteString]
  .dropWhile(_.isEmpty)
  .prefixAndTail(1)
  .flatMapConcat { case (bstr, restBstrs) =>
    if (bstr.head.head == 0x16)
      restBstrs.via(protocol.join(tlsBidi))
    else
      restBstrs.via(protocol)
  }
```

This is still pretty gross though - the encryption layer is no longer as tidily tucked away into a `BidiFlow`. Instead, I need to restructure the surrounding code to accommodate the encryption layer. :(